# Looping through a list (or dict) when using python-docx-template (docxtpl)

Tags: python, python-docx

EDIT:  I must admit I screwed up and hadn't downloaded all of the examples/tests.  I downloaded the entire package and found awesome examples that showed me how to do everything I wanted to do.  This particular issue is shows in `dynamic_table_tpl.py` and `dynamic_table.docx`.

I am using python-docx-template and have created a DOCX template.  I have been trying to use jinja2 formatting as the documentation suggests.  I need to add a series of addresses into my DOCX file.  That data is from a database and I'm pulling it from the DB using python.

Here's what I have in the DOCX Template file:

```
{% for kid in kids %}
{kid.first}{kid.last}
{kid.addr1}{kid.addr2}
{kid.city}{kid.state}{kid.zip}  

{% endfor %}
```

This is in my .py file:

```
kids = [
    [
        ('first','John'),
        ('last','Williams'),
        ('addr1','5555 NW 37th St')
        ('addr2','Apt 2601')
        ('city','Oklahoma City')
        ('state','OK')
        ('zip','73112')
    ],
    [
        ('first','George'),
        ('last','Lucas'),
        ('addr1','1234 Dobbs St.')
        ('addr2','Suite 62')
        ('city','Moore')
        ('state','OK')
        ('zip','73160')
    ]
]

context = {
    "kids" : kids
}
```

I've looked in the documentation and examples and have not found out how to make this work.  If I have 2 kids in the database, I would like the result to look something like this:

```
John Williams
5555 NW 37th St., Apt 2601
Oklahoma City, OK 73112

George Lucas
1234 Dobbs St., Suite 62
Moore, OK 73160
```

The template is not replacing anything in the loop.  It is writing both of the loops in the created DOCX where in the Template I have the `for kid in kids` loop only written once.  It's reading it in some way, but not exactly how I need it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using tuples (the bracket thing) , it is not possible to reach the elements without a numeric index. Therefore the best thing to do is accessing them via an index like `kid[1]`, or otherwise turn the tuple into a dictionary prior accessing it (IMO this is the most reliable)